# Visual Studio adding global:: in IntelliSense

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio keeps adding `global::` namespace for classes instead of omitting it. Even though it later says to remove it. How can I change this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Do you have reference to two assemblies with the same namespaces?

Comment: Hm not really, this is a Unity project. It worked fine under VS 2012. (this is 2015.)

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Also with a Unity project

Comment: Same here, with Unity project.

Answer (score 1):

This happens for me because I have some class with a namespace of a different project.